# HTML select option set selected default echo get value php

Tags: php, html, css, select

I have a simple HTML form with a simple select like this

```
<select name="myselect"  selected="<?php echo $_GET['brand'];?>">

<option value="" <?php if($brand== "") echo "selected"; ?>>all brands</option>
<option value="samsung" <?php if($brand== "samsung") echo "selected"; ?>>Samsung</option>
<option value="motorola" <?php if($brand== "motorola") echo "selected"; ?>>Motorola</option>

</select>
```

What I am trying to do is because its a search filtering results form if the user choose Samsung as default brand to search next page with filteres search results will the select option default selected Samsung and no other. If user select to search Motorola then the selected option default will be Motorola.

How do I fix this?

Comment: remove `selected="<?php echo $_GET['brand'];?>` in the `select` tag

Comment: `select` doesn't have `selected` attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[selected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) is attribute of `option` not `select`, so remove it from `select` tag, change to:

```
<?php $brand = trim( strtolower($_GET['brand']) ); ?>
<select name="myselect">

<option value="" <?php if($brand== "") echo "selected"; ?>>all brands</option>
<option value="samsung" <?php if($brand== "samsung") echo "selected"; ?>>Samsung</option>
<option value="motorola" <?php if($brand== "motorola") echo "selected"; ?>>Motorola</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Simple Example of selected=selected by using foreach loop and ternary operators in php... use can easily understand and customize that code...

```
<?php $plan = array('1' => 'Green','2'=>'Red' ); ?>
    <select class="form-control" title="Choose Plan">
    <?php foreach ($plan as $key => $value) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php echo ($key ==  '2') ? ' selected="selected"' : '';?>><?php echo $value;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $selected_brand = $_GET['brand'];

$temp_str = '';
$temp_str .= '<select name="myselect">';

$brands_array = array("all" => "all brands", "samsung" => "Samsung", "motorola" => "Motorola");
    foreach ($brands_array as $key => $value) {
        if($key == $selected_brand){
            // For selected option.
            $temp_str .= '<option value="'.$key.'" selected>'.$value.'</option>';
        } else {
            $temp_str .= '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
        }
    }

$temp_str .= '</select>';

echo $temp_str; // Select box.
?>
```