# input name[] to store values in html/php

Tags: php, html, json, post

I have a **php/html** code as shown below. The below html/php code is working in a way that on adding rows, we can select date from every row and can save it as well.

Here is the [script](https://jsfiddle.net/47b6eu39/2/embedded/result) which I have used in order to add a row.

```
<?php
$output = array();     
$output['house_sitting_date']=$_POST['house_sitting_date'];

$fp = fopen('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
fclose($fp);

if(file_exists('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json')){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json'));
}
?>

<?php if($data) { ?>
<form method="post">
        <!-- Select Date START -->
        <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4>
            <input type="date" id="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date[]" value="<?php if($data->house_sitting_date<>''){echo $data->house_sitting_date;}?>">
        </div>
        <!-- Select Date END -->
 </form>
<?php } else {
echo 'Cannot read JSON settings file';
}
?>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that when we add a row and then after selecting date in every row, everything should get saved in the `JSON`.

At this moment, nothing is getting saved in the JSON (../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json) after saving the form.

---

What I want to achieve is after saving the form, it should display the selected date from each individual row we have added.

Comment: Please don't continually delete and repost the same question. Give people a chance to answer the first time.

Comment: @Nick Sorry about that. I am wondering if you are able to understand my question. On saving the form, nothing is getting saved in the JSON. Is this the right way to use house_sitting_date[] array in input tag ? I am using JavaScript to add a row.

Comment: Don't use flat files for storing data. You are heading for a world of pain.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` < add that to your php script(s), and tell us if you get errors back. I asked you to check for errors in the first question but didn't get a response about it.

Comment: I don't see any code in your question that involves writing to a file. You probably want something like `get file contents; if (POST set) { merge with file contents; write back to file }`

Comment: `$data->{" house_sitting_date "}` can be written simply as `$data->house_sitting_date`. You only need the `{}` syntax if the property is dynamic or contains special characters.

Comment: Your JSON data needs to be an array of objects. Then you can put each element of the array in a different row of the form. You'll need to put the index or other identifier of the object in the row, either as part of the `name` attribute or a hidden input field.

Comment: @Barmar I have modified it to $data->house_sitting_date Also, which JSON data needs to be an array of objects ? I am wondering if you can give me more hint how this can be done.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I will do that tomorrow and i am at home currently and I am unable to VPN into my machine.

Comment: @flash If you have multiple rows of data in the form, they need to correspond to multiple objects in the JSON file. That's done by putting an array in the file instead of a single object.

Comment: Or maybe `$data->house_sitting_date` needs to be an array. I'm not really sure what your application is doing.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47b6eu39/2/embedded/result). You will get an idea what my application is doing. After adding a row, we can select date from each individual row. After selecting date from each individual row, we can save the form.

Comment: What I want to achieve is after saving the form, it should display the selected date from each individual row we have added.

Comment: @Barmar I have included fiddle (with no php code) to give audience an idea what my application is doing. It is working in a way that when we can select the date from each individual row we have added, it should display the selected dates after saving it, The dates will be stored here ../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json

Comment: Ok. Check what Barmar submitted. I noticed it just now. I made a slight edit to your question containing what you said in  comments. I thought it might help.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Sure, I had a look. I will give a try at 9am EST. For some reasons, I am unable to VPN into my office machine.

Comment: Not a problem. I hope this turns out to be what you were looking for, or very near. *Fingers crossed*, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `house_sitting_date` property an array of dates. Then you can loop over them when creating the form, and write the entire array back into the JSON file when the form is submitted.

```
<?php     
$output['house_sitting_date']=$_POST['house_sitting_date'];

if(file_exists('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json')){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json'));
}
?>

<?php if($data) { ?>
    <form method="post">
        <?php if (empty($data->house_sitting_date)) { ?>
            <!-- Select Date START -->
            <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
                <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4>
                <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date[]" value="">
            </div>
            <!-- Select Date END -->
        <?php } else {
                foreach ($data->house_sitting_date as $date) { ?>
            <!-- Select Date START -->
            <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
                <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4>
                <input type="date" class="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date[]" value="<?php if($date)){echo $date;}?>">
            </div>
            <!-- Select Date END -->
        <?php } ?>
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['house_sitting_date'])) {
        $data->house_sitting_date = $_POST['house_sitting_date'];
        file_put_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json', json_encode($data));
        echo "JSON file updated";
    }
} else {
    echo 'Cannot read JSON settings file';
}
```

Also, you should not use the same ID on repeated elements, IDs are supposed to be unique. Use `class="house-sitting-date"` instead of `id="house-sitting-date"` if you need to target it with CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: Sure, I will try with this code at 9am EST. Unfortunately, I am unable to VPN into my office machine at this moment.

Comment: I will use id instead of class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think we are getting close. Everything is getting saved in the JSON now. Thanks for the hep in regards with that.

Comment: The only minor (very minor) issue which I am having right now when JSON is empty (when users haven't added any row) then audience can't select any date. Users have to click **Add New Row** button 
in order for the date rows to be visible.  I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that on page load (when JSON is empty and when no row is added), one default row 
should always be present there.

Comment: Check the length of `$data->house_sitting_date`. If it's zero, otherwise go into the loop that displays the contents.

Comment: I have used **if statement** when JSON is empty. When JSON is not empty, it would go inside else statement.    https://3v4l.org/hg1C1

Comment: I tried with the logic above but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it's the same logic, except I don't use `$date` in the `if` block, since the variable only exists in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. It worked for me. Everything is working perfectly fine. I have a similar question for **<select> name array attribute**. This is what i have tried. https://3v4l.org/fQo61 I am wondering if you can give me some pointer how to fix that. In the dropdown list, I have 3 items: Please choose an option, Yes, No. The issue which I am having right now is on selecting/saving an item from the drop-down list, nothing is getting pulled from the JSON all rows get deleted like in the previous situation.

Comment: You shouldn't put `$yes_no` in the `value` attribute. The values should be `nada`, `yes`, and `no`, and for each option you test whether `$yes_no` equals that option's value; if so, you add the `selected` attribute.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644349/html-select-option-set-selected-default-echo-get-value-php for an example. If you can't figure it out, you need to ask a new question, not post comments.